# Submitting Python Script as Dataflow Job

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I have a simple processing job that I want to submit as a Dataflow job. It is just a python file that takes a csv as input, applies two models to the input, and adds the output to the csv. How do I submit this as a Dataflow job? I can do it on my local machine, but whenever I try to submit on GCP, it gives me an error:

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has 
Python 3.7 interpreter.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "predict_DF.py", line 119, in <module>
run()
File "predict_DF.py", line 113, in run
p.run()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 513, in run
allow_proto_holders=True).run(False)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 526, in run
return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 582, 
in run_pipeline
self.dataflow_client.create_job(self.job), self)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 236, in wrapper
return fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 
659, in create_job
self.create_job_description(job)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 
712, in create_job_description
io.BytesIO(job.proto_pipeline.SerializeToString()))
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 
637, in stage_file
response = self._storage_client.objects.Insert(request, upload=upload)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1156, in Insert
upload=upload, upload_config=upload_config)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 729, in _RunMethod
http, http_request, **opts)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 350, in MakeRequest
check_response_func=check_response_func)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 400, in _MakeRequestNoRetry
redirections=redirections, connection_type=connection_type)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 169, in new_request
redirections, connection_type)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 169, in new_request
redirections, connection_type)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1991, in request
cachekey,
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1651, in _request
conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1558, in _conn_request
conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
self.send(chunk)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 987, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1034, in sendall
v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1003, in send
return self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.timeout: The write operation timed out
```

Here is my code besides the imports:

command line

```
python predict_DF.py \ 
--region $REGION \
--input $INPUT \
--output $OUTPUT \
--text_extraction_model $TEXT_EXTRACTION_MODEL \
--model $MODEL \
--translation_dictionary $TRANSLATION_DICTIONARY \
--runner $RUNNER \
--project $PROJECT \
--temp_location $TEMP_LOCATION \
--staging_location $STAGING
```

predict_DF.py

```
   def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
   """Main entry point; defines and runs the prediction pipeline."""
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
       parser.add_argument(
       '--input',
       dest='input',
       required=True,
       default='/Users/me/input.csv',
       help='Input file for predictions'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output',
        dest='output',
        required=True,
        default='/Users/me/output.csv,
        help='Output file to write results to'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--model',
        dest='model',
        required=True,
        default='/Users/me/model.joblib'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--text_extraction_model',
        dest='text_extraction_model',
        required=True,
        default='/Users/me/tfidfit',
        help='Text extraction model for processing input'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--translation_dictionary',
        dest='translation_dictionary',
        required=True,
        default='/Users/me/id_to_category',
        help='Dictionary relating numerical id to classification group'
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    model = joblib.load(known_args.model)
    tfidfit = pickle.load(open(known_args.text_extraction_model, 'rb'))
    id_to_category = pickle.load(open(known_args.translation_dictionary, 'rb'))



    def get_pred(x):
        pred = id_to_category[model.predict(tfidfit.transform([x]).toarray()).tolist()[0]]
        return pred

    def parse_method(line):
        import csv
        reader = csv.reader(line.split('\n'))
        for csv_row in reader:
            values = [x for x in csv_row]
            row = []
            for value in csv_row:
                if value != None:
                    row.append(value)
            row.append(get_pred(row[16]))
        return ",".join(row)

    lines = (p | beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input) |
         'Split' >> beam.Map(lambda s: parse_method(s)) |
         'Output to file' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output)
         )

    p.run()

run()
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: socket.timeout: The write operation timed out

Comment: Full traceback?

Comment: added to the post

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with apitools, or a firewall, or something like that. Can you execute any gcloud commands, e.g. `gcloud dataflow jobs list`?

Comment: yes. I do so regularly.

Comment: yes, I just ran that and it worked.